# Unity some of the object comes with wrong axis from blender fbx file

Tags: unity-game-engine, blender

The problem I have is simple. When I export my file in a blender as fbx and import it to the unity, the objects (or part of the objects for some reason) turn into the wrong axis while it looks ok in both blender and fixes file. I looked at google for this problem. Most of them did not help me. I saw that coding might help.  I found a code that can help me which is this:

`transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0, transform.eulerAngles.y, 0);`

But the problem remains because it changes all of the rotation of the road, so the right roads become wrong while wrong roads become right. Putting this in the necessary planes might work but there are so many planes and I will put more planes in the blender project in the future so it won't help me too much.

I have two options.

1. Write a code that changes it to the right axis if the plane/object looks at the wrong axis.
2. Find the right way to import it.

I don't how to do any of the time since I am a beginner. I use Unity 2019.4.33f1 and Blender 2.83. Please help me

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/13Y-lnccTvNPWPKAT520CCM8u-7MgaXkR?usp=sharing

Thank you

EDIT: I put my blender file to the drive link as well.

EDIT2: I keep editing I know but I realize that I have another problem as well. The problem is that Unity gets my object wrong, for example, I have a half green half red object and I want both colors to be at the +y axis. It makes the red part at -y axis. Here are the pictures: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1ob5xdKv0nPHN3TSABHGDVA7inW8vkag6?usp=sharing
How can I fix this :'(

LAST EDIT: I found a way to solve it. I added the same object twice but one of them has a different setting. Assume that rotations are 0 0 0 (x y z respectively) and scales are 1 1 1 (x y z respectively). The second road will be different settings from the first road. Its rotation settings will be 0 0 180 and the scale will be -1 1 1. Of course, I am open to better suggestions but this is the solution I found.

SOLUTION: After a long time later, I finally found the answer. I updated this in case someone needs it later. All I had to do was calculate the normals again and the way we do is, after choosing all of the roads, **Edit Mode -> Mesh -> Normals -> Recalculate Inside / Recalculate Outside**

Answer (score 0):

Blender uses a left handed coordinate system, where the Z axis points upwards, whereas Unity uses a right handed coordinate system, where the Y axis points upwards. There might be some extensions or packages to keep them the same, however you probably just have to rotate the model in Unity or Blender to fit your needs.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I was actually planning to do that but I encounter another problem. For example, you have an object which is yellow ut you decided to change half of the color to green then import it to the unity. You wait an object looks half yellow and half green but unity (even though unity knows its a whole object) make +y axis yellow and -y axis to green. Thats my problem right now. Here are the pictures of my problem so you can understand better. https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1ob5xdKv0nPHN3TSABHGDVA7inW8vkag6?usp=sharing